# I noticed that there's a difference between using bitshifting and n^power in python: Can someone explain why?

Tags: python, bit-shift

First one:

```
    for i in range(4):
         return (1 << i)
```

Second one:

```
for i in range(4):
     return (2^i)
```

Can someone explain why there's a difference between the 2?

Comment: @Abadis: it's true about the return statement, but there is still a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the power syntax is `**` not `^`:

```
>>> [2**i for i in range(4)]
[1, 2, 4, 8]
>>> [1 << i for i in range(4)]
[1, 2, 4, 8]
```

Note: `^` (hat) is for [bitwise exclusive or](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions).

Comment: Not to mention that it would have to be `2 ** (i + 1)` to match up to `2 << i`. (And also, good luck having a `return` statement in a for loop...)

Comment: I'd add that `^` is for bitwise `xor`.

Comment: bitshift hacks have no place in python, really.  leave that to the C guys!